# Why Django does not suggest null=True on string based fields?

Tags: django

Django official documentation does not suggest using `null=True` on string based fields. [[source]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null)

I understand that they don't like to have two different `no data` value. Because of this, Django suggests only use empty string as `no data` value. But, Why they didn't choose `None` over `""` (empty string)?

Answer (score 1):

When both NULL and the empty string mean "no data", you want to chose one for consistency. If you have the choice, go for type stability, which is easier to handle with strongly typed languages - i.e. empty string. But sometimes you don't have the choice.

Suppose that you inherit a database where the string fields are nullable, and many lines are already populated with NULL. Often times some application in front of it is expecting NULL values from the database and is handling them.

Now if you are told to connect a Django service to the same database, you don't want to break the logic by writing empty strings for no value, because the other app would treat them wrongly. For instance, instead of correctly showing a warning, it would print the empty string silently.

When the value always comes from a form though, there is no way for a user to make a distinction between a NULL and an empty string when sending data or when data is loaded to pre-fill the form.

So my answer is that if the form is the only way to write the data in database, the empty string is probably a better choice for the sake of type stability, while if the form is not the only source, you must adapt to the meaning of values already present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

@JulienD has the right of it for the purposes of knowing type, but there's also a practical end to it in terms of templates. Say you have a table you're rendering with the attributes of an object. You probably want a missing value to be empty. If you used NULL for that you get the Python `None`, which if you use `{{ model.field }}`in your template will render as `None`. To avoid that, you'd have to only print the value if the isn't `None` and check it manually or use a template filter.

Whereas if you used `blank=True`, you can just insert the value in the template without worrying. A empty value just inserts a `''`.